# webview is working on earlier versions, but not on Oreo

Tags: android, webview

i was making a simple app that uses a webview and display my website inside my activity. The code is working fine in Earlier version of android but crashing my app on Oreo Emulator and real device..
Searched all over but didn't find any solution. is there any alternate to webview???

this is my code..

```
WebView client = findViewById(R.id.Display);

client.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

client.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

client.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Logcat:

> 11-13 11:58:06.754 4369-4453/com.example.oreinsoft.matrix E/chromium:
>   [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(289)] eglChooseConfig failed with error
>   EGL_SUCCESS 11-13 11:58:06.986 4369-4453/com.example.oreinsoft.matrix
>   E/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: EGL_BAD_CONFIG: no ES 3 support
>   11-13 11:58:06.987 4369-4453/com.example.oreinsoft.matrix
>   E/EGL_emulation: tid 4453: eglCreateContext(1488): error 0x3005
>   (EGL_BAD_CONFIG) 11-13 11:58:06.987
>   4369-4453/com.example.oreinsoft.matrix E/chromium:
>   [ERROR:gl_context_egl.cc(180)] eglCreateContext failed with error
>   EGL_BAD_CONFIG 11-13 11:58:08.560
>   4369-4430/com.example.oreinsoft.matrix E/chromium:
>   [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(132)] Renderer process (4397) crash
>   detected (code 6). 11-13 11:58:09.114
>   4369-4369/com.example.oreinsoft.matrix A/chromium:
>   [FATAL:aw_browser_terminator.cc(75)] Render process (4397)'s crash
>   wasn't handled by all associated  webviews, triggering application
>   crash. 11-13 11:58:09.115 4369-4369/com.example.oreinsoft.matrix
>   A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4369
>   (reinsoft.matrix), pid 4369 (reinsoft.matrix)

Comment: `but crashing` with  exception and stacktrace which will tell you what is a problem, and which you have to show here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: edit your question and add your crash logcat

Comment: Thank you for response.. I have posted the logcat as.. it is working on android 6.0 and later devices.